# XNA - trying to use an IF to detect 2 gamepad presses at same time with no avail

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

Basically I have a task at college where I have to display the button presses of a gamepad from an xbox controller on the screen when they are pressed.

I have images to represent the gamepad presses and all the coordinates set out. I can get the buttons to appear when they are pressed... however. I must have the diagonal presses on the dPad to appear, without the corresponding buttons you need to press "NOT" apearing. I also need to have the triggers fade in with transparency as they are slowly pushed into their maximum value.

like this : [Image of how the program should look when keys are pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxcka.gif)

I have the problem that when I press up and right together... all three images light up on screen (instead of just the diagonal up/right image).

I have basically set out IF statements within my drawing method to draw the specific images when they are pressed and to colour them each with a different colour, like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(under, underPos, Color.White);
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Triggers.Right == 1.0f)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(rightTrigger, rTriggerPos, Color.White);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Triggers.Left == 1.0f)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(leftTrigger, lTriggerPos, Color.White);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(right, rightPos, Color.Red);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(left, leftPos, Color.Blue);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(up, upPos, Color.Yellow);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(down, downPos, Color.Green);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(upRight, upRightPos, Color.Orange);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(downRight, dRightPos, Color.Brown);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(upLeft, upLeftPos, Color.Cyan);
        }
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(downLeft, dLeftPos, Color.Purple);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
```

My problem is I don't know how to combine the two IF statements to just show the one diagonal image, can you combine two IF statements or game presses at the sametime?... and how do you get the triggers to slowly increase in colour and transparency... can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Consider `if (rightIsPressed && leftIsPressed)`. For the triggers, check out [Color.Lerp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.color.lerp(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx).

Comment: the Color.Lerp was very useful, thank you

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple conditions passed in an If statement using && for AND and || for OR.

I would use else if instead of multiple if simply for clarity in this instance.
Just a sample snippet from your code exercising this:

`else if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed && GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
  spriteBatch.Draw(upLeft, upLeftPos, Color.Cyan);
}`

This will make the condition pass ONLY if both UP and LEFT are pressed at the same time.

Hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: I did that, and I also added else if statements, but because I have four buttons to press there are still things combining with each other. I need some kind of way of isolating each 4 combo presses.. so up&right/right&down/down&left/left&up. So that when each combo is pressed, the other two singular ones aren't executed at the same time.

Comment: You can accomplish this in two ways. Make more encapsulating else-if statements but this can because quite hard to read after awhile. I would suggest making a bool method which will contain its own logical rules for when two buttons are pressed. If two buttons are pressed, the bool will return true for instance. then use this as a conditional statement inside of an else if and execute only if the bool statement is true.

Comment: Edit: The reason you are getting multiple buttons becoming colors is because the code needs more logic to determine When NOT to color something. In conjunction with what is mentioned above. Add that bool statement to each method which determines if only one button is being pressed. If not THEN execute this "if" statement "else" execute some other statement.